# Какие последствия могут быть если Enity не соответствует схеме БД

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine2

Какие могут быть последствия, проблемы если Enity не соответствует схеме базы данных. К примеру у меня есть класс сущности SKU и его описание. В нем определено свойство `$amountOfPackaging`.

```
/**
 * Количество в упаковке
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision = 10, scale = 3)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
```

1. Какие могут быть последствия/проблемы, если я на уровне БД изменю разрядность данного поля к примеру 10.4?
2. К чему может привести объявленные связи на уровне БД и не описаны в классах Enity.

Comment: А почему бы вас просто не протестировать?

Comment: Попробовал. На уровне БД убрал все связи, оставил только на уровне Doctrine, также изменил разрядность нескольких колонок в таблице.  Пока последствий не было.

Comment: Ну вот и все )) если вы хотите более точно узнать, то обратитесь в исходные коды доктрины, в которых я , увы, не силен

Comment: Скорее всего такие точности при описании колонки нужны для создания таблиц из сущностей

Comment: Вопрос с разрядностью я задал для полноты картины, больше  интересовали связи. Интересный момент получается на уровне БД связи нет зато логическая осталось по идеи в таком варианте возможно должна увеличится производительность сервера БД, но я не уверен.

Comment: На вряд ли, ведь благодаря связям вы делаете свою бд целостной, а это очень важно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2. К чему может привести объявленные связи на уровне БД и не описаны в классах Enity.

Я считаю, что потенциально могут возникнут проблемы при попытках удаления таких сущностей. Доктрина не знает о связи, БД знает. Доктрина пропустит операцию - БД нет.

Также, если нечайно (понимаю, это маловероятно) запустить команду `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete` - то она уберет все изменения из БД, которые не соответствуют схеме данных доктрины.

Кроме этого, вижу в этом проблему в усложнение самого приложения, ведь теперь придется держать в голове, не только классы сущностей, но и помнить о связях в самой БД, прописанные отдельно. И сложнее будет реализовывать бизнес-логику, если знание об отношениях явно не определенны в классах сущностей.

Кроме этого, я бы задумался еще и о деплое. Ведь связи могут измениться. Как с этим быть?